# Sidebars with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a few side bars which are being included in my blade view via @include('sidebar-1').

I'm wondering what the best approach would be when populating these sidebars with data from the database? I wont need them on every page & I have not had to deal with anything like this, I tend to pass data through the routes or the controller but I don't have a route for the side bar ^^

Any guidance is appreciated! I think the answer may be something along the lines of refactoring the way I'm including these sidebars.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think View Composers are what you need:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.

I use view composers for the exact situation you describe. When a particular sidebar view is rendered, Laravel automatically calls the view composer that prepares the data for that sidebar.

Comment: Ahhh! This looks very promising, I'm currently building with Laravel 5.1 however. This has me on the correct route though! Thanks :D

Comment: Ok I updated the link for 5.1. =) It's the same thing, View Composers haven't changed in 5.2.

Comment: Upvotes all round! Have a great evening mate, thank you :D